# How do I make there be no group owner of a file in Mac OSX?

Tags: permissions, osx, group, ownership

How do I make there be no group owner of a file in Mac OSX, since

```
chgrp nogroup file
```

doesn't work? If I try, the group owner doesn't change at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `chgrp nobody file` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  Every file has to have an owner and a group.

There is, however, a common convention of having a user called `nobody`  (usually with uid 65534) and a group called either `nobody` or `nogroup` (usually with gid 65534).

e.g. on my debian systems, I have:

```
$ getent group nogroup
nogroup:x:65534:

$ getent passwd nobody
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

if `nogroup` doesn't exist on your Mac, try `chgrp nobody file` instead.

Comment: This answer jogged into mind a question I've had for a while, which I decided to [post separately](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/272047/135943).